# Calling method of object passed to qt plugin yields symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I have a problem with passing a object to Qt Plugin and when trying to get its member using const member function i get symbol lookup error. Example:

This is inside Qt application:

```
class A{
    int a,b,c;
}; 

class B{
public:
    const QList<A*>* a() const { return m_a; }
private:
    QList<A*>* m_a;
};

class C{
public:
    const B* b() const { return m_b; }
private:
    B* m_b;
};
```

This is inside QtPlugin:

plugin.h

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"

//....
```

plugin.cpp

```
void Plugin::somefunc(C* c)
{
    qDebug() << c->b()->a()->count();
}
```

If I call from Qt application somefunc() of a plugin I get symbol lookup error:

```
symbol lookup error ... plugin.so undefined symbol _ZNK5b6a
```

but if I put B and C class members into public domain it works using:

```
    qDebug() << c->m_b->m_a->count();
```

Did anyone have similar problem or knows how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: I still couldn't believe that you can call m_a.count() as m_a is a pointer

Comment: I wrote this test case here in SO. Actual class names are different. Now fixed. I wrote first test case with references so . operator stuck, forgot to change it but whether it is reference or pointer it, when running application and launching plugin code it throws mentioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this "problem".

- **Make shared library** - make shared library and move code that application and QtPlugin use into that library
- **Add .h and .cpp of files used to QMake file** - header and source files of application used in QtPlugin add to HEADERS and SOURCES directive in .pro file - this is actually static linking

I haven't found similar question on web, and thus putting this answer. Maybe question was fuzzy, sorry about that. Thanks for answer. This answer is for any future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Class members are private by default. `B::a()` and `C::b()` are private. To be able to call these member functions from `Plugin::somefunc()` you need to make them public explicitly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to put _public:_ in this test case, and compiler would give me error. Methods are public for this example and I get symbol lookup error while executing the program. Application and plugins compiles.